# Old version of app appears in simulator

Tags: xcode

When running my app on the simulator, a old version of the app shows up on the simulator (both on the iPad simulator and on my iPad). I have tried:

Cmd+alt+shift+k
Product -> Clean

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Delete it (long press and press the X) ?

Answer (score 1):

Reset the settings of the simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The apps on your simulator are installed at:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications
```

Try navigating to there in your finder and manually removing the old application.